# A problem relative to skew-symmetric bilinear forms

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $( \cdot, \cdot )$ be the skew-symmetric bilinear form on $\mathbb{C}^4$ defined by the matrix:
$$
\left (
\begin{array}{cccc}
0& -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0& 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
How can I find all the subspaces $V$ of $\mathbb{C}^4$ such that $(w, v)=0$ for $v, w \in V$? Note that this is different from finding the subspaces $V$ such that $(w, v)=0$ for all $v \in V$ and $w \in \mathbb{C}^4$.

Comment: Your form is nondegenerate, so $\{0\}$ is the only possible $V$.

Comment: The problem is not so symple. Consider for example $v=(1, 1, 1, 1)$, for which $(v, v)=0$.

Comment: Ok, sorry. My comment was wrong.

Comment: Do you mean the form $B(u,v) = u^TAv$ or the [sesquilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) $B(u,v) = u^*Av$?

Comment: $B(u,v)=\sum_{i,j} u^*_j A_{ij} v_i$

Answer (score 0):

A potentially helpful perspective; too long for a comment.

---

For convenience, denote
$$
A = \left (
\begin{array}{cccc}
0& -1 & 0 & 0 \\
1& 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0& 0 & 0 & 1 \\
0& 0 & -1 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$
The bilinear form you describes defines a unique map $\phi: \Bbb C^n \otimes \Bbb C^n \to \Bbb C$ given by
$$
\phi(u \otimes v) = u^TAv
$$
Note that for each subspace $V$ you describe, we have $V \otimes V \subset \ker \phi$. Similarly, if $W \otimes W \subset \ker \phi$, then for $u,v \in W$, we have $u^TAv = 0$.

Thus, it suffices to describe the sets $V \otimes V \subset \ker \phi$. Perhaps these are easier to find?